# Prevent div contents from overflowing

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class = "board"  style = " min-height: 80px; border-radius: 3px;  background-color: #e2e4e6;  ">

  <div class = "list" style = "white-space: normal; width: 240px; min-height: 35px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 5px; " contenteditable = "true" data-placeholder = "Add a List..."></div> 

  <div  style = "width: 250px; height: 35px; margin-top: 5px;">
    <input class = "save"  type="button" value="Save"  style = "cursor: pointer; width: 60px; height: 30px; background-color: gray; border-color: gray; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 3px; vertical-align: top;" >

    <img class = "close" src = "media/icons/close.png" width="27" height="27" style = "cursor: pointer; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 5px;">     
  </div>

</div>
```

This code is works fine for me. And when I click on the save button, the contents are save to another div.

```
$('.save').on('click', function() {
        var listName = $('.list').text();
```

Here I am save the text.

```
var listNameContent = $('<div class  = "list-name-content">'+ listName +'</div>');
```

But the contents are too long, it overflow to the outside of the div. I want all the texts inside of my div. I tried the **white-space, word-wrap** these are not works for me. Please help me.   Thank You.

Comment: Please show an example of content that is overflowing. There's nothing overflowing in the example HTML.

Comment: Have tried setting "overflow:hidden" css rule to your div?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the div contents from overflowing you will add this to your `css`

```
// to hide the contents
overflow: hidden;

// to make a scroll bar for the contents
overflow: auto;
```

The `auto` will automatically create the scroll bars if there is an overflow

Comment: but I don't want show the scroll bar. Scroll bar should be hidden.

Comment: If you don't want the scroll bars to show then you use `overflow:hidden;` but if you don't want the text to be hidden also the use the `word-wrap:break-word;`

Answer (score 1):

Use [**word-wrap**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

```
.someClass{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/c2c6toak/)